# Dynamically populate tabs with the right content in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

I'm trying to learn angularJS, and I wanted to do a simple app which populate tabs dynamically using Json data.

I have two tables in my db, City and Country. so a Country have many Cities and a City have only one Country.

Lets say :

Country :

- countryId : 1, countryName : France
- countryId : 2, countryName : England

City :

- cityId : 1, countryId : 1, cityName : Paris
- cityId : 2, countryId : 1, cityName : Marseille
- cityId : 3, countryId : 2, cityName : London
- cityId : 4, countryId : 2, cityName : Southampton

I created a simple api that have only two methods actually :

GET /api/City give me that JSON (all the cities) :

```
    {
    "City":[
    {
     "cityId" : 1,
     "countryId" : 1, 
     "cityName" : Paris
    },
    ...
    ...
    ]
    }
```

And GET /api/Country give me that JSON (all the countries) :

```
    {
    "Country":[
    {
     "countryId" : 1,
     "countryName" : France
    },
    ...
    ...
    ]
    }
```

I want to have something like this in my view :

Tab France -> Content : Paris Marseille

Tab England -> Content : London Southampton

So the two tabs must have the name of the two countries , and they must have their cities as a content.

Everything must be dynamic because later I want to implement two interfaces in order to give the possibility of adding Countries ( tabs ) and Cities by choosing a Country with a < select >.

In my controller, I do two $http requests, one on /api/City and i fill $scope.TabsContent with the data and the other on /api/Country in $scope.Tabs.

I already achieved to dynamically create the two Country tabs ( with ng-repeat on $scope.Tabs) and they show the right container when i click on them.

My problem here is to fill those two containers with the right cities that are in $scope.TabsContent. ( Paris and Marseille in France tab / London and Southampton in England tab ).

I tried in many ways, but no success. I think I do not used the right approach..

**EDIT :**

Here's the code (simplified) :

HTML :

```
    <body ng-app="countriesAndCities" ng-controller="MainCtrl">


      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="mytab">
          <li ng-repeat="Tab in Tabs"  ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">
              <a href="#tab{{$index + 1}}" data-toggle="tab">{{Tab.name}}</a>
          </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab{{$index + 1}}" ng-repeat="Tab in Tabs" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">

                    Tab n° {{$index + 1}}

          </div>
      </div>

  </body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('countriesAndCities', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$('#mytab').tab('show');

// This is what I got from $http request, simplification in hardcode here :

    var Tabs = [{"countryId":"1","countryName":"France"},{"countryId":"2","countryName":"England"}];

// Same for the cities :

 var TabsContent = [{"cityId":"1","countryId":1,"cityName":"Paris"},{"cityId":"2","countryId":1,"cityName":"Marseille"},{"cityId":"3","countryId":2,"cityName":"London"},{"cityId":"4","countryId":2,"cityName":"Southampton"}];



});
```

So actually, I have two tabs France & England, and their contents are "Tab n° 1" for France tab and "Tab n°2" for England tab.

How do i replace "Tab n°1" by "Paris Marseille" and "Tab n°2" by "London Southampton" by using $scope.TabsContent ?